# Error compiling material design with laravel 6

Tags: laravel, webpack, material-design, laravel-6, laravel-mix

from a couple of days, I started a new project with laravel 6 and I'm trying so hard to make it work with [material design web component](https://material.io/develop/web)
but every time I run the command `npm run watch` i got the same error in my terminal  I tried to use the `"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",` but its didn't work and the error is:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                    
2:01:59 PM

error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@use "material-components-web/material-components-web";
^
  Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "material-components-web/material-components-web";
 stdin 1:1  root stylesheet
  in /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/resources/sass/app.scss (line 1, column 1)
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:52:13
at Function.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:88191:16)
at _render_closure1.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:77610:12)
at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26152:18)
at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26156:19)
at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24600:19)
at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24897:40)
at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4311:88)
at _Future._completeError$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24725:9)
at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24117:12)
at Object._asyncRethrow (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4065:17)
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:14087:20
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4090:15)
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24138:12)
at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24130:25)
at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26152:18)
at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26156:19)
at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24600:19)
at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24897:40)
at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4311:88)
at _Future._completeError$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24725:9)
at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24117:12)
at Object._asyncRethrow (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4065:17)
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:16672:20
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4090:15)
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24138:12)
at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24130:25)
at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26152:18)
at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26156:19)
at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24600:19)
at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24897:40)
at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4311:88)

 error  in ./resources/sass/app.scss

 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

 @use "material-components-web/material-components-web";
 ^
  Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "material-components-web/material-components-web";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  stdin 1:1  root stylesheet
  in /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/resources/sass/app.scss (line 1, column 1)

  @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-201

 Asset    Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
 /js/app.js  10 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

 ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                                                                                                                                    
 ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
@use "material-components-web/material-components-web";                                                                                                                                                              
^                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  Can't find stylesheet to import.                                                                                                                                                                               
  ╷                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
1 │ @use "material-components-web/material-components-web";                                                                                                                                                          
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                                           
  ╵                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
stdin 1:1  root stylesheet                                                                                                                                                                                         
  in /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/resources/sass/app.scss (line 1, column 1)                                                                                                                                  
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20                                                                                                                               
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11                                                                                                                         
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18                                                                                                                         
at context.callback (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)                                                                                                      
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:52:13                                                                                                                                  
at Function.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:88191:16)                                                                                                                     
at _render_closure1.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:77610:12)                                                                                                             
at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26152:18)                                                                                                             
at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26156:19)                                                                                                               
at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24600:19)                                                                                                       
at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24897:40)                                                                                    
at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4311:88)                                                                                                 
at _Future._completeError$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24725:9)                                                                                                             
at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24117:12)                                                                                                
at Object._asyncRethrow (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4065:17)                                                                                                                 
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:14087:20                                                                                                                                       
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4090:15)                                                                                           
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24138:12)                                                                                              
at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24130:25)                                                                                                      
at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26152:18)                                                                                                             
at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26156:19)                                                                                                               
at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24600:19)                                                                                                       
at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24897:40)                                                                                    
at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4311:88)                                                                                                 
at _Future._completeError$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24725:9)                                                                                                             
at _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24117:12)                                                                                                
at Object._asyncRethrow (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4065:17)                                                                                                                 
at /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:16672:20                                                                                                                                       
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.$protected (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4090:15)                                                                                           
at _wrapJsFunctionForAsync_closure.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24138:12)                                                                                              
at _awaitOnObject_closure0.call$2 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24130:25)                                                                                                      
at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26152:18)                                                                                                             
at _RootZone.runBinary$3 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:26156:19)                                                                                                               
at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24600:19)                                                                                                       
at _Future__propagateToListeners_handleError.call$0 (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:24897:40)                                                                                    
at Object._Future__propagateToListeners (/home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:4311:88)                                                                                                 
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss                                                                                                                                                                                         

 ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-4!./resources/sass/app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
@use "material-components-web/material-components-web";                                                                                                                                                              
^                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  Can't find stylesheet to import.                                                                                                                                                                               
  ╷                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
1 │ @use "material-components-web/material-components-web";                                                                                                                                                          
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                                                                                                                                           
  ╵                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 stdin 1:1  root stylesheet                                                                                                                                                                                         
  in /home/amratef/projects/xoon_app/resources/sass/app.scss (line 1, column 1)                                                                                                                                  
 @ ./resources/sass/app.scss 2:14-201                                                                                                                                                                                
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:8001
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
      Local: http://localhost:3004
    External: http://192.168.1.6:3004
 ------------------------------------
      UI: http://localhost:3005
 UI External: http://localhost:3005
 ------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Watching files...
```

**And these are my dependencies in package.json file**

```
    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "axios": "^0.19",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.12",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.13",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.11.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@material/auto-init": "^7.0.0",
    "@material/button": "^7.0.0",
    "@material/icon-button": "^7.0.0",
    "@material/mwc-button": "^0.17.2",
    "material-components-web": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-mdc-adapter": "^0.18.2"
}
```

**and this is the content of the app.scss file**

```
@use "material-components-web/material-components-web";
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';

$test-color:green;

.testing{   
   color: $test-color;
}

#navbar-example2,
HTML,
body {
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

**and this is the content of the app.js file**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
window._ = require('lodash');
window.axios = require("axios");
require('bootstrap');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
import autoInit from '@material/auto-init';
autoInit();
import * as mdc from 'material-components-web';
```

**and this is the content of the webpack.mix.js file**

```
const path = require('path');
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.autoload({
jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
'popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js': ['Popper']
});
mix.copy('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts', 'public/webfonts')
  .js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
  .sass( 'resources/sass/app.scss', "public/css",{
    implementation: require('sass'),
    webpackImporter: false,
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: ['./node_modules']
    }
    
})
.options({
    processCssUrls: false
});

if (mix.inProduction()) {
mix.version();
}else{
mix.browserSync('http://localhost:8001/')
.sourceMaps();

}
```

so please can anyone help me with this :(

Comment: Have you tried `@use "~material-components-web/material-components-web"` ?

Comment: yes, but didn't work :(

Comment: are you sure you are supposed to import the components like that? In the documentation the provided example only includes specific components, such as `@use('~@material/icon-button')`

Comment: yes I tried  this approach but didn't work